# Equality of two objects

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Objects are equal by there reference not there values.

```
var obj1 = {name: 'Yousef', age: 15},

    obj2 = {name: 'Yousef', age: 15};

console.log(obj1 === obj2); // The Result will be false
```

However, This rule doesn't seem to apply on DOM Objects:

```
var div1 = document.querySelector('div'),

    div2 = document.querySelector('div');

console.log(div1 === div2); // The Result will be True!
```

Can anyone explain why?

Comment: Because they are the same object?

Comment: obj1 has the same value as obj2 but they don't have the same reference, so they are not equal

Comment: Yes, they have the same reference -- they *are the same object* - pointing to the same DIV.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your first example is comparing two *separate* objects. Your DOM example is comparing **one** object to itself. `querySelector` doesn't *create* an object, it returns you a reference to the object that *already exists* in the DOM tree.

The equivalent to your DOM example would be this:

```js
function findElement(element, tag) {
    for (var n = 0; n < element.children.length; ++n) {
        var child = element.children[n];
        if (child.tag === tag) {
            return child;
        }
    }
    return null;
}

var tree = {
    children: [
        {
            tag: "child",
            name: "I'm the child element",
            children: []
        }
    ]
};

var obj1 = findElement(tree, "child");
var obj2 = findElement(tree, "child");
console.log(obj1 === obj2); // true
```

Answer (score 3):

Because when you use `querySelector` you find the first and only the first DOM element which match your query.

So div1 and div2 are the same object

Comment: they have the same value but not the same reference so they shouldn't be equal!

Comment: @YousefEssam: No, they **are** the same object reference.

Comment: the DOM is an object. when you use querySelector, you search an object inside and object.
so div1 and div2 are link to the same object. But with obj1 and obj2, you create two object with the same value, they took 2 differentes places inside your RAM

Answer (score 1):

Let's try to understand from [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)

> Returns the first Element within the document that matches the specified selector, or group of selectors.

So no matter how many times you call, you get the same Element right ??

Yes it is. `querySelector` won't create any objects, it just traverse through DOM and returns the matched object.  Even this point also mentioned in the doc

> Note: The matching is done using depth-first pre-order traversal of the document's nodes by first element in document markup and iterating through sequential nodes by order of amount of child nodes).

In your first case, you yourself creating objects.